# jQuery adding dynamic HTML to a variable with a loop

Tags: jquery, html

I need to have an input text box create a table and X amount of rows / input & select boxes into a specific `<div>` on my page, I'm trying to use a loop to accomplish this..

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="input_boxes" id="input_boxes" size="5" style="font-size:0.9em;">
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE ROWS ARE DISPLAYED FOR CALCULATION-->
<div id="calculator_rows" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;"> </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_boxes').keyup(function(){
        //Get Number of Rows Needed
        var txtVal =  $('#input_boxes').val();
        var morehtml ='';
        for(i=1;i<=txtVal;i++){
            var morehtml =+ '<tr><td><select name="select_type[]" id="select_type"> <option value="Box">Box '+i+'</option> <option value="Bag">Bag '+i+'</option><option value="Skid">Skid '+i+'</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="calc_tot[]" size="5"></td></tr>';   
        }
        $('#calculator_rows').html('<table border="1"><th>Box/Bag/Skid</th><th>Quantity</th>'+ morehtml +'</table>');
    });
});
```

Comment: `var morehtml =+` should be `morehtml +=` don't redefine variable

Comment: `var morehtml =+` should be `morehtml +=` (was referring to A. Wolff previously editted comment)

Comment: could catch, shouldn't re-define the var in the loop. fixed that but still seeing same results.

Comment: @nodsdorf please fix += in your question too

Comment: @nodsdorf you are just doing it wrong, re-read comments please. This is the second one, NOT first one... And its '+=' not '=+'

Comment: looks like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vE5QA/1/

Comment: OP please don't re-edit question with now working code, this makes your question and btw following answers pointless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for(i=1;i<=txtVal;i++){
       morehtml += '<tr><td><select name="select_type[]" id="select_type'+i+'"> <option   value="Box">Box '+i+'</option> <option value="Bag">Bag '+i+'</option><option value="Skid">Skid'+i+'</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="calc_tot[]" size="5"></td></tr>';   

         }
```

Comment: Thank you all, that was it, redfining the var and should have been +=

Comment: Thank you all again, you had it right from the beginning I missed just a few thing, and appreciate the help. Not sure why you had to neg me. But thank you anyway.